# Error "Cannot read property 'status' of undefined" after post request and page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My goal is to do this follow of actions :

1. POST request
2. Reload page
3. DELETE request

However, when I do the DELETE request I got this error :

```
VM360 main.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (VM360 main.js:68)
    at u (VM357 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM357 jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (VM357 jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM357 jquery.min.js:2)
```

This is because `response` is undefined on Delete method. I don't understand why ...

Can you explain me why this error occured? And how to solved it?

Thanks for help!

**JS**

*Post*

```
function newReservation() {
    let data = {
        "titre" : $("#titreoeuvre-newreservation").val(),
        "idusager" : $("#idUsagerNewReservation").val()
    };
    envoyerRequete('/reservations', data, "POST").always(function (response) {
        if(response.status.toString().startsWith('2')) {
            $('#newreservation-danger').hide();
            $('#newreservation-success').modal('show');
        }
        else {
            $('#newreservation-danger').show();
        }
    });
}
```

*Reload*

```
$('.modal-success-ok').click(function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

*Delete*

```
function annulerReservation() {
    let data = {
        "titre" : $("#titreoeuvre-annulation").val(),
        "idusager" : $("#idUsagerAnnulerReservation").val()
    };
    envoyerRequete('/reservations', data, "DELETE").always(function (response) {
        if(response.status.toString().startsWith('2')) {
            $('#annulerreservation-danger').hide();
            $('#annulerreservation-success').modal('show');
        }
        else {
            $('#annulerreservation-danger').show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That probably means response is undefined. Do a `console.log(response)` before the `if(response.status...)`

Comment: @Aniket G yes it's `undefined` but why? Because delete works on database... How an ajax response can be undefined?

Comment: The POST request probably didn't return something